# Find the current and previous designation of a Employee in q/kdb+

Tags: kdb

Find the current and previous designation employees by comparing current date with previous updated

`` flip dc:`eid`name`titleID`title`lastupdate!(("1234" ;"1234"; "1234" ;"9835" ;"9835"; "9835"; "0982");("Jhon";"Jhon";"Jhon";"Chris";"Chris";"Chris";"jack");("09561";"08123";"08123" ;"07812"; "05234"; "05234"; "08123");("SalesManager";"Salesexecutive";"Salesexecutive";"SeniorSalesExecutive";"Salesexecutive";"Salesexecutive";"salesmanager");2023.06.26 2023.06.25 2023.06.20 2023.06.26 2023.06.25 2022.06.20 2022.01.19) ``

**EmployeeTAB**

| eid | name | titleID | title | lastupdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "1234" | "Jhon" | "09561" | "Sales Manager" | 2023.06.26 |
| "1234 " | "Jhon" | "08123" | "Sales executive" | 2023.06.25 |
| "1234" | "Jhon" | "08123" | "Sales executive" | 2022.06.20 |
| "9835" | "Chris" | "07812" | "Senior Sales executive" | 2023.06.26 |
| "9835" | "Chris" | "05234" | "Sales executive" | 2023.06.25 |
| "9835" | "Chris" | "05234" | "Sales executive" | 2022.06.20 |
| "0982" | "Jack" | "08123" | "Sales Manager" | 2022.01.19 |

Query `select from EmployeeTAB where lastupdate<td,lastupdate=(max;lastupdate) fby eID;` results the latest updated result

**output**

| eID | name | titleID | title | lastupdate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "1234" | "Jhon" | "09561" | "Sales Manager" | 2023.06.26 |
| "1234" | "Jhon" | "08123" | "Sales executive" | 2023.06.25 |
| "9835" | "Chris" | "07812" | "Senior Sales executive" | 2023.06.26 |
| "9835" | "Chris" | "05234" | "Sales executive" | 2023.06.25 |

Comment: When asking a question involving such sample tables please include a `q` statement to create them to help those answering. The question also needs more detail. Are you unhappy with the query included and it's output? or is it that the query is what you have attempted but did not give the correct output?

Answer (score 2):

Remove employees with only 1 role using `fby`.

Sort remaining by id and latest date and group the table on eid.

Then just `take` the first 2 entries and `ungroup`

```
`eid xasc ungroup 2#''`eid xgroup`eid`lastupdate xdesc select from employeeTAB where 1<(count;i)fby eid
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve desired result is to

1. Get reference table of `eid`s and two most recent `lastupdate`s
2. Join reference table with other data by `eid` and `lastupdate`

Like below

```
(ungroup select -2#asc lastupdate by eid from EmployeeTAB) 
  ij `eid`lastupdate xkey EmployeeTAB
```

Deleting employees, who only had one role makes query more complicated:

```
delete from distinct (
  (ungroup select -2#asc lastupdate by eid from EmployeeTAB) 
    ij `eid`lastupdate xkey EmployeeTAB
) where 1=(count;eid) fby eid
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (assumes data is sorted by lastupdate as per the sample):

```
q)select from EmployeeTAB where({(1<count x)&x&not 2<sums x};lastupdate<=.z.D)fby eid
eid    name    titleID title                  lastupdate
--------------------------------------------------------
"1234" "Jhon"  "09561" "SalesManager"         2023.06.26
"1234" "Jhon"  "08123" "Salesexecutive"       2023.06.25
"9835" "Chris" "07812" "SeniorSalesExecutive" 2023.06.26
"9835" "Chris" "05234" "Salesexecutive"       2023.06.25

q)select from EmployeeTAB where({(1<count x)&x&not 2<sums x};lastupdate<=2023.06.25)fby eid
eid    name    titleID title            lastupdate
--------------------------------------------------
"1234" "Jhon"  "08123" "Salesexecutive" 2023.06.25
"1234" "Jhon"  "08123" "Salesexecutive" 2023.06.20
"9835" "Chris" "05234" "Salesexecutive" 2023.06.25
"9835" "Chris" "05234" "Salesexecutive" 2022.06.20
q)
```

Answer (score 0):

`res:(select  from employeeTab where lastupdate<=tradingDate,lastupdate=(max;lastupdate) fby eid) lj 1! select eid,prevTitleID:titleID,prevTitle:title,preLastupdate:lastupdate from employeeTAB where lastupdate<=tradingDate,lastupdate=(max;lastupdate) fby eid`

`select from res where titleID<>prevTitle, not prevtitle like ""`